# CSS div not adapting to the content

Tags: html, css, height, scrollable

If there are so much text in a div (e.g. conversationList or conversation), I want that I can scroll down to read more. My problem is that div's wont resize themself. It's like they are all fixed. Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21x4d5yj/).

HTML

```
<body>
   <header>
        Text
   </header>
   <main>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">LINK 1</a><br>
            <a href="#">LINK 2</a><br>
            <a href="#">LINK 3</a><br>
            <a href="#">LINK 4</a><br>
        </nav>

        <section id="pageTitle">
          Title
         </section>

         <section id="conversationList">
           List of Items
         </section>

         <section id="conversation">
           Conversation
         </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is `div` in your demo?

Comment: Problem is your `position:fixed` in your `main` tag.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked this mistake :/

Comment: Since a div has that behavior by itself, you broke it by your own CSS. A constructive way to solve this, is break down your CSS to see which style broke the default behavior. This will make it easier for yourself and others to find an solution, and you will gain a deeper understanding yourself about side effects of certain properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, if you remove the position: fixed from your css for the "main" element it will let the section expand with its content.

Edit: Only remove it from main, not from header and you'll still have a fixed header.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked this mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

Try add this style for scrolling div:

```
overflow-y: scroll; 
height:400px;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want a scrollbar in my div. It should only get bigger (increase of height)

Comment: Increase of height to which section? there is no div in your demo